# checkout stripe with plugin contact form

Tags: plugins, ajax, jquery, google-chrome

I have an issue with stripe, i am using the plugin contact form 7 stripe & paypal addon, but when i fill the form with my bank informations and i click on checkout button the page is stuck and the payment stay in load.

When i open my console on chrome i have this errors :

```
ui-shared-effa3a053bc4ef4561898ec62ce92736.js:1 Refused to load the image 
'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'some code' because it violates the following 
Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' https://q.stripe.com".
```

and

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:1
```

Thank you for any help provide !

Answer (score 0):

your ajax not responding there(it's taking a lot of time).

please check plugin compatible with current wordpress version or not?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
```

/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:1